# Spring Data JPA projection issue with field starting with IS in kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using interface based projection to get certain fields from db. one of my field name start with `is`. I'm able to get the field from database via native query, however, the response returned by spring boot controller does not contain `is` in field name. How should I resolve it?

```
interface UserProjection {
    val userId: Long
    val isPrivate: Boolean
    val likesCount: Int
}
```

Query

```
SELECT u.user_id as userId, u.is_private as private, u.likes_count as likesCount FROM users u WHERE u.user_id=?;
```

However, response returned by spring boot is

```
{
  "userId": 12345,
  "private": false,
  "likesCount": 1
}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the 'as private' part?

Comment: It throws error stating, null value found for non-null property `isPrivate`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a fun to get the field instead of a val

```
interface LoginUserProjection {
    val id: Long
    val passwordHash: String
    fun getIsVerifiedAccount(): Boolean
}
```